# Sign in API end point wont get invoked unless you clear the browsers cache and then reload the page

Tags: asp.net, reactjs, .net, azure, web-applications

I have made a website using asp.net and I have set up a sign-in feature that uses OpenID specifically Steam. I have a web API that gets called and that procs the challenge for the open id. When the user clicks sign in it opens a new tab and browser and direct them to sign in api point. On my local pc, it works perfectly however on a hosted app service on Azure it does not. When the window opens it does not call the API. The only way to call the API is to clear the cache (Shift + Ctrl + R). This then reloades the page and the API get called and it works perfect. If I dont clear the cache its just a blank page.

Here is the code for the API

```
    [HttpPost("api/signin"), HttpGet("api/signin")]
            public async Task<IActionResult> SignIn(string type)
            {
                string provider = type;
                // Note: the "provider" parameter corresponds to the external
                // authentication provider choosen by the user agent.
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(provider))
                {
                    return BadRequest();
                }
    
                if (!await HttpContext.IsProviderSupportedAsync(provider))
                {
                    return BadRequest();
                }
    
                // Instruct the middleware corresponding to the requested external identity
                // provider to redirect the user agent to its own authorization endpoint.
                // Note: the authenticationScheme parameter must match the value configured in Startup.cs
                return Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "api/saveuser" }, provider);
            }
```

Here is the code for the function that opens the new window and points to the API when a button is pressed.

```
 handleLoginSteam = () => {
        let winHeight = window.screen.height / 1.5;
        let winWidth = window.screen.width / 3;
        const win = window.open(
            '/api/signin?type=Steam',
            'Discord Sign In', "height=" + winHeight + ",width=" + winWidth + ",top=" + ((window.screen.height - winHeight) / 2) + ",left=" + ((window.screen.width - winWidth) / 2));
        win.opener.location.reload();
        const timer = setInterval(() => {
            if (win.closed) {
                clearInterval(timer);
                this.fetchUserData();
            }
        }, 500);
    }
```

[This is a picture of the new window not calling the api](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9O4ie.png)

At this point pressing ctrl shift r is the only way to invoke the steam sign in.

I tried adding a random parameter to the link that gets passed to the window to stop caching but it doesnt work!
If any one can help me out I would be greatly apreciated im quite new to asp.netS.

Answer (score 0):

Went through the code seems you are trying to achieve **opens the new window and points to the Signin API when a button is pressed and RefreshParentWindow task**. Now, based on your code let’s take a look at your code line-by-line.

This is the code to open a popup window.

```
const win = window.open(
            '/api/signin?type=Steam',
            'Discord Sign In', "height=" + winHeight + ",width=" + winWidth + ",top=" + ((window.screen.height - winHeight) / 2) + ",left=" + ((window.screen.width - winWidth) / 2));
```

On the same page(I assume) you have

```
win.opener.location.reload(); //this will refresh the parent window
        const timer = setInterval(() => {
            if (win.closed) {
                clearInterval(timer);
                this.fetchUserData();
            }
        }, 500);
    }
```

setInterval() It repeats the statements in the specified intervals REPEATEDLY. Now, you are checking if the window is still opened or not using this line of code.

```
if (win.closed)
```

this check every second even if the window is closed!

Reference: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_closed.asp

Now follow these steps:

1. Open child window using the script on your parent page(you already have it there).
2. Get rid of the code that checks if the window is closed or not. You don't need it, in any way.
3. When you are done with adding a new record from you child window call these statements.

```
opener.location.reload();  //This will refresh parent window.
window.close();   //Close child window. You may also use self.close();
```

The above two lines will be written on the child page. Maybe on buttons click.

```
<input type="button" onclick="Signin()" value="Signin" />

function AddRecord(){
//Add newrecord.
opener.location.reload(); //This will refresh parent window.
window.close(); //Close child window. You may also use self.close(); 
}
```

Reference : https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1097734/How-to-reload-refresh-the-parent-window-after-chil